# Angular: let user select a material icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

In an angular (v8) application, I want the user to be able to select a material icon within a list. A solution can be a list of such icons (that I display in a select) or a lib (with search abilities).

Can't find anything by googling, do you know something like this?

Thks.

Comment: can you provide any sample example or provide example in stackblitz.com. It may easy to find out solution.

Comment: I don't have any code yet. My goal is to do the same as https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=accessible&style=baseline or https://jossef.github.io/material-design-icons-iconfont/ i.a. display all available icons et let the user select one. I only need the icon name at the end.